# Separar un string de acuerdo a la mayúscula en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, funciones

Tengo que separar el nombre de una variable que me viene de la base de datos, es decir vienen dos palabras juntas (camel Case) y la quiero separar en la mayúscula y cambiar la primer letra por mayúscula también.

> **nameparams: "autoRojo"**   ----------> De esa manera me llega
>
> **nameParams: "Auto Rojo"**  ---------> Así debería quedar

Tengo que hacer una función para separar el nombre y que quede como resultado final **Auto Rojo**.

Llevo horas intentando hacerlo y no se me ocurre nada, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript
Esto devuelve la posición del regex que le pases. Así, podrás hacer un regex de solo mayúsculas y partir el string en ese punto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comenté, un regex para saber en que posición poder cortar el string es algo que podrías usar.

```js
let nombreJunto = "autoRojo"
var match = /[A-Z]{1}/.exec(nombreJunto);
let indexSplit = 0
if (match) {
  indexSplit = match.index
}
let nombre = nombreJunto.substring(0, indexSplit)
let apellido = nombreJunto.substring(indexSplit)

console.log(nombre, apellido)
```

A partir de aquí, ya puedes hacer lo que necesites con los textos separados